# Unable to use PHPIZE after update to MacOS Mojave

Tags: php, macos-mojave, phpize

What i should do when i run PHPIZE and get the error below ? I already installed xcode command line tools.

> ```
> grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
> grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
> grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
> Configuring for:
> PHP Api Version:        
> Zend Module Api No:     
> Zend Extension Api No:
> ```

Comment: do you have `/usr/include/php/main/` and `/usr/include/php/main/php.h`?

Comment: No, none of these exists on my system. Actually there is no /usr/include folder. Maybe in Mojave is another folder ?

Comment: it seems that your os move or remove some file.you can re-install php

Comment: I'm using the default PHP installation of Mac Os Mojave. It probably changed folder locations

Comment: I found this resource invaluable: https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/xdebug-catalina

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Potential better solution - force reinstall the header files. Fixed a ton of problems for me system wide.

Running the following command will reinstall the developer tools header files and should fix the issue.

```
$ sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Comment: Not potential. Absolutely the better solution.

Comment: Thanks. This works and fixes everything for the OS installed PHP. I came across this issue while trying to setup xdebug.

Comment: had need to run `xcode-select --install` first. after a re-install of my OS xcode was gone. i guess.

Comment: It appears the new version of Xcode may have removed this pkg. I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Before I could run the above command I also had to re-install Xcode developer tools from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/
and specifically had to select "Command Line Tools (macOS 10.14) for Xcode 10.2"

Comment: How to apply this solution for MacOs Catalina ?

Comment: @delphirules have you found a solution for MacOS Catalina?

Comment: @AbanaClara Not yet, i opened a new quesiton : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58693002/unable-to-use-phpize-after-update-to-macos-catalina

Comment: This does not work for me. I get the following error: ```"The install failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.)"```

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, I found `Xcode command line tools` was not installed completely on my Mac, Finally I solved this problem as follow:

```
 1. xcode-select --install
 2. cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/ 
 3. open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Note: After doing step2, if there is no `.pkg` file in the dir. maybe this solution will not help you.

Answer (score 2):

find the phpize and edit it,

```
~$ whereis phpize
phpize: /usr/local/bin/phpize
~$ vim  /usr/local/bin/phpize
```

in my `phpize` script it is like that

```
prefix='/usr/local/php7'   ## where you should edit
datarootdir='/usr/local/php7/php'
exec_prefix="`eval echo ${prefix}`"
phpdir="`eval echo ${exec_prefix}/lib/php`/build"
includedir="`eval echo ${prefix}/include`/php"
...

phpize_get_api_numbers()
{
  # extracting API NOs:
  PHP_API_VERSION=`grep '#define PHP_API_VERSION' $includedir/main/php.h|$SED 's/#define PHP_API_VERSION//'`
  ZEND_MODULE_API_NO=`grep '#define ZEND_MODULE_API_NO' $includedir/Zend/zend_modules.h|$SED 's/#define ZEND_MODULE_API_NO//'`
  ZEND_EXTENSION_API_NO=`grep '#define ZEND_EXTENSION_API_NO' $includedir/Zend/zend_extensions.h|$SED 's/#define ZEND_EXTENSION_API_NO//'`
}
```

if you comfirm that you have the header file  but the phpize script configure is wrong ,you can edit the  row

`prefix='/usr/local/php7'`

and `php.h` is in

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/php7/include/php/main
$ ls  php.*
php.h
```

if not ,you can compile php by yourself

Comment: My php folder is /usr/local/php5-7.1.10-20171002-090111 . i edited prefix='/usr/local/php5-7.1.10-20171002-090111' and datarootdir='/usr/local/php5-7.1.10-20171002-090111/php', but i still get the same error when calling PHPIZE... any hints ?

Comment: Actually this file : "/usr/include/php/main/php.h" is on "/usr/local/php5-7.1.10-20171002-090111/include/php/main"

Comment: do you have more than one phpize script?

Comment: No. I could solve the problem after doing what you suggested., thanks !

Comment: Now i upgraded to Catalina, i'm having the same issue, but i can't edit phpize anymore even as sudo, i get this error : "Failed to save 'phpize': Command failed: "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" --file-write "/var/folders/dc/3d93lth116q91kx94ms37rd40000gn/T/code-elevated-dynago" "/usr/bin/phpize" Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/usr/bin/phpize'"

Comment: `phpize` is a readonly file. even cannot be edited by `sudo`

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue as described above, only I was trying to install xdebug on macOS Mojave.

I resolved the issue by executing:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Comment: duplicate answer.