# I can not install GRPC on Mac OS X Mojave

Tags: php, macos, grpc, pecl

I use the mac `mojave` and am trying to install the `grpc`:

```
sudo pecl install grpc
```

I use MAMP.

The triggered error is:

> / bin / sh
>   /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-root9h4CAG/grpc-1.16.0/libtool
>   --mode = compile cc -fvisibility = hidden -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM -D_GNU_SOURCE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS = 0 -DNOMINMAX -DGRPC_ARES = O-1. -I / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I / private / tmp / pear / install / pear-build-root9h4CAG / grpc-1.16.0 / include -I / private / tmp /
>   pear / install / pear -build-root9h4CAG / grpc-1.16.0 / main -I /
>   private / tmp / pear / install / grpc -I / usr / include / php -I /
>   usr / include / php / main -I / usr / include / php / TSRM -I / usr /
>   include / php / Zend -I / usr / include / php / ext -I / usr / include
>   / php / ext / date / lib -I / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc /
>   include -I / private / tmp / install / grpc / src / php / ext / grpc
>   -I / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc / third_party / boringssl / include -I / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc / third_party /
>   address_sorting / include -I / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc /
>   third_party / nanopb -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wall -Werror
>   -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-unused-value -std = c11 -g -O2 -D PB_FIELD_32BIT = 1 -c / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc / src /
>   php / ext / grpc / byte_buffer.c -o src / php / ext / grpc /
>   byte_buffer.lo mkdir src / php / ext / grpc / .libs  cc -fvisibility =
>   hidden -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM -D_GNU_SOURCE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
>   -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS = 0 -DNOMINMAX -DGRPC_ARES = 0 -I. -I / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I / private / tmp / pear /
>   install / pear-build-root9h4CAG / grpc-1.16.0 / include -I / private /
>   tmp / pear / install / pear -build-root9h4CAG / grpc-1.16.0 / main -I
>   / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc -I / usr / include / php -I /
>   usr / include / php / main -I / usr / include / php / TSRM -I / usr /
>   include / php / Zend -I / usr / include / php / ext -I / usr / include
>   / php / ext / date / lib -I / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc /
>   include -I / private / tmp / install / grpc / src / php / ext / grpc
>   -I / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc / third_party / boringssl / include -I / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc / third_party /
>   address_sorting / include -I / private / tmp / pear / install / grpc /
>   third_party / nanopb -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Wall -Werror
>   -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-unused-value -std = c11 -g -O2 -D PB_FIELD_32BIT = 1 -c
>   /private/tmp/pear/install/grpc/src/php/ext/grpc/byte_buffer.c
>   -fno-common -DPIC -or src / php / ext / grpc / .libs / byte_buffer.o /private/tmp/pear/grpc/src/php/ext/grpc/byte_buffer.c:19:10: fatal
>   error: 'php.h' file not found
>   #include <php.h>
>            ^ ~~~~~~ 1 error generated. make: *** [src / php / ext / grpc / byte_buffer.lo] Error 1 ERROR: `make 'failed

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You have to install (if you already didn't) the command line tools

```
xcode-select --install
```

And also add the headers (they are not added in Mojave)

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Credit to @donatJ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612102/649915