# Mac Mojave PHP 7.19 configuring with xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug, macos-mojave

I have recently updated my macbook pro to mojave which has updated PHP to 7.19. The problem is that xdebug has stopped working. I tried editing /etc/php.ini adding in the previous entries for xdebug, but now when I start apache I get the following:

`Failed loading /usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so, 0x0009): code signature in (/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so) not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.`

So I thought I'd try and reinstall xdebug - `sudo pecl install xdebug` - this fails with the following errors:

`/bin/sh /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFbhymt/xdebug-2.6.1/libtool --mode=compile cc   -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFbhymt/xdebug-2.6.1/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFbhymt/xdebug-2.6.1/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c -o xdebug.lo
mkdir .libs`

`cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFbhymt/xdebug-2.6.1/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFbhymt/xdebug-2.6.1/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/xdebug.o`
`/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/xdebug.c:25:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found`

`#include "php.h"`

`^~~~~~~`

`1 error generated.`

`make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 1`

`ERROR:`make' failed`

This a bit above my pay grade to sort out I think... it looks like for some reason php.h can't be found, but now I'm stuck!

How do I resolve this?

**EDIT**

As an update to this, I can also see that phpize is failing when I run the command:

`

```
downloading xdebug-2.6.1.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.6.1.tgz (283,961 bytes)
..........................................................done: 283,961 bytes
79 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
```

`

I did find this post [Unable to use PHPIZE after update to MacOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592548/unable-to-use-phpize-after-update-to-macos-mojave) where someone was having the same problems, but I don't really get it... do I have to change the contents of phpize file, what to?

Comment: try completely remove php, reinstall and build xdebug. if still error and no solution, let consider MAMP

Comment: In the post you mentioned, is an another solution. No need to edit phpize, just reinstall the headers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612102/6540060