# Unable to use PHPIZE after update to MacOS Catalina

Tags: php, macos, macos-catalina

That's life : new MacOs upgrade, new issues.

Just like happened in Mojave ([Unable to use PHPIZE after update to MacOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592548/unable-to-use-phpize-after-update-to-macos-mojave)), I can't use PHPIZE anymore in Catalina.

I tried the solution purposed in the question above, but when i try to edit and save PHPIZE in VSCode, i get the error below :

> Failed to save 'phpize': Command failed: "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" --file-write "/var/folders/dc/3d93lth116q91kx94ms37rd40000gn/T/code-elevated-snaie" "/usr/bin/phpize" Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/usr/bin/phpize'

Any hints ?

Comment: I haven't installed Catilina yet but my guess from your error message is you need to turn off system integrity protection? https://donatstudios.com/Disable-macOS-System-Integrity-Protection

Comment: I was stuck in the same boat, but if you are using the built-in Apache and PHP. I would suggest installing the ones from Homebrew to save yourself a whole world of problems. I posted a question yesterday and answered it today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707883/how-to-load-memcached-on-php-in-mac-os-x-catalina. `phpize` works perfectly afterwards