# Has anyone successfully built PHP 7.4 extensions on MacOS 12.4 using PECL?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, pecl, phpize

I'm using homebrew to install PHP on macOS 12.4 (Monterey), and having difficulty getting the suggested PECL extension install method to work.  I've installed php 7.4 on macOS:

```
brew install php@7.4
```

And then I ran the following `pecl install` command to install a PHP extension, as an example:

```
pecl install bz2
```

I get the following failure:

```
WARNING: "pear/bz2" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://php.net/bzip2/ext/bz2"
downloading bz2-1.0.tgz ...
Starting to download bz2-1.0.tgz (7,168 bytes)
.....done: 7,168 bytes
3 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I read some other posts mentioning that `pecl install` might be broken now and that the packages need to be downloaded, built, and installed in separate steps.  I then tried to perform a build of the binaries from the downloaded source by running the following:

```
pecl download bz2
pecl bundle bz2
cd bz2
pecl build
```

I get a build failure ending with the following log:

```
...

checking for PHP prefix... /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29
checking for PHP includes... -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/include/php -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/include/php/main -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/include/php/Zend -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/include/php/ext -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/pecl/20190902
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking for BZip2 support... yes, shared
checking for BZip2 in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the BZip2 distribution
`/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/bz2/configure --with-php-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/bin/php-config' failed
```

I tried to install BZip2 using `brew install BZip2`, verified installation and PATH registration for the package, restarted the terminal, and got the same error.

The bz2 extension is just one example but I haven't been able to get any of the pecl bundles to install or build successfully.

I'm wondering if anyone has had success building and installing PHP 7.4+ extensions on macOS 12+, and if so, what was your method to get these packages to properly build on this setup?

Comment: this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592548/unable-to-use-phpize-after-update-to-macos-mojave

Comment: Thanks for the link - unfortunately the accepted answer there doesn't work for me since the package at that path doesn't exist on my version of macOS.  I'll see if I can find an analog for Monterey but I did already attempt to install the latest xcode build tools just in case

Comment: you definitely need `xcode`, also you need `brew install libzip` since you have this error `checking for BZip2 in default path... not found`